# How do I express $\displaystyle\sum_{r+s+t=n}a_{r,s,t}$ explicitly as nested sums, where $r,s,t,n$ are positive integers?

Tags: summation

How do I express $\displaystyle\sum_{r+s+t=n}a_{r,s,t}$ explicitly as nested sums, where $r,s,t,n$ are positive integers? That is to say, how can I express it in the following way...

$$\sum_{r+s+t=n}a_{r,s,t}=\sum_{r=r_0}^{R}\sum_{s=s_0}^S\sum_{t=t_0}^Ta_{r,s,t},$$
where $r_0,s_0,t_0,R,S,T$ are to be found. I went through the following possible combinations:

$$\begin{array}{l|l|&l}
r&s&t\\
\hline
0&0&5\\
0&1&4\\
0&2&3\\
0&3&2\\
0&4&1\\
0&5&0\\
\hline
1&0&4\\
1&1&3\\
1&2&2\\
1&3&1\\
1&4&0\\
\hline
2&0&3\\
2&1&2\\
2&2&1\\
2&3&0\\
\hline
3&0&2\\
3&1&1\\
3&2&0\\
\hline
4&0&1\\
4&1&0\\
\hline
5&0&0\\
\end{array}
$$

So I should be able to do something like:

$$\sum_{r=0}^5\sum_{s=0}^{5-r}\sum_0^{t=5-r-s}a_{r,s,t},$$

where the strange indexing in the most inner sum denotes counting down - not sure if I can just write it the usual way without having to denote this in a special way?

I think this is right. Can it be generalised for more variables, e.g. $r+s+t+u=n$, $r+s+t+u+v=n$, etc.? Perhaps there's a standard way to do this and my brain's just not working right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main idea is correct but you messed up at the last element. The correct answer is:

$$\sum_{r=0}^5 \sum_{s=0}^{5-r} a_{r, s, 5 - r - s}$$

This is because $r + s + t = n$ rearranged gives $t = n - r - s$. In other words, $t$ is fully determined by $r$ and $s$.